# Problems verifying and running javascript (html5 canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jslint, three.js

For one of my courses I need to program a 3D application in html5 canvas. For this I chose to use Three.js. For now, all I'm trying to do is render a simple plane. I also want to be able to move the camera along the x-axis by holding down the mouse and dragging. I based my code on the code found [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/webgl/html5-canvas-webgl-plane-with-three-js/). It's basically a plane which is spinning around (or the camera is circling around the plane, not sure which). I threw away all the code for the animation and added code for mousedown, mousemove, etc events. When I load the page it renders the plane (inanimate) just fine, but when I try to use my mouse to move it around it remains completely unresponsive. In my code you may have noticed I changed some things I maybe shouldn't have (made some variables global and changed some function names) in order to get things working, but the result remained the same.

This is the first time I'm working with javascript and I realize I can't just change existing code and expect it to work. I looked into javascript verification and I found JSLint. I downloaded the plugin for notepad++ and tried to verify my code that way. It doesn't like the html tags and it especially hates the Three.js library I'm trying to import. It doesn't pick up on it when I import it as [url](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js) and it doesn't import it when I download it and import the file either. When I just copied the code of the entire library into the file it just gave me a lot of errors about the library itself and stopped verifying somehwere before my code even started.

In conclusion: I would like some help with the project itself but also with setting up a pleasant development environment (with proper verification that doesn't ignore imports).

Finally, my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas demo</title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var camera;
var scene;
var plane;
var renderer;
var clickX;
var clickY;
var mousedown;

window.onload = function () {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.y = -450;
    camera.position.z = 400;
    camera.rotation.x = 45;

    //scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //plane
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 300), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}));
    plane.overdraw = true;
    scene.add(plane);   

    rerender(); 
};

window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback){
        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

function rerender(){
    //render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    //request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function(){
        rerender();
    });
}

$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
  clickX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;       
  mousedown = true;
});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
    if(mousedown) {
        var xDiff = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - clickX;
        camera.position.x = xDiff;      
        rerender();
    }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
  mousedown = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
  mousedown = false;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not much happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/TVWYn/

Comment: jsFiddle fixed to include both Three.js and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/TVWYn/2/ -- however, I'm still not seeing any plane.

Comment: I changed the url you put in the html to the one of the library (like the one in my question) and it shows the plane just like it does in my browser: http://jsfiddle.net/TVWYn/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various issues here that are preventing your code from running properly. I've gone through and fixed them, and you can now move the camera along the x-axis:

http://jsfiddle.net/TVWYn/6/

Your issues were:

1. You're using jQuery and not including the jQuery library. The dollar
   sign function is not part of JavaScript, it's (in this case) part of
   a third-party library called jQuery that makes working with the DOM
   easier. Without including the jQuery library, your mouse handlers
   couldn't run.
2. Even with jQuery included, the order in which your setup functions
   executed was incorrect. Originally you had your Three.js setup
   process such that it would execute once the DOM was initialized.
   That's good. However, you were trying to register mouse event
   handlers immediately after the JS was acquired by the browser. This
   is not good. You're asking JS to attach mouse event handlers to DOM elements that don't exist at that point in time. To fix this,
   you need to ensure that the DOM has been initialized (ex. running your setup inside a `window.onload`) and your
   required elements have already been inserted (in this case,
   `#canvas`). Or, attach your event handlers to the DOM objects directly (ex. `renderer.domElement`).
3. You were referencing `#canvas` without ever setting the `id` of your
   canvas element.

With regard to setting up a proper development environment, I would strongly suggest that you start using Chrome and its developer tools (which are launched via `ctrl`+`shift`+`j`).

Comment: Many thanks! Looks like I can get to work now :) I would tag your answer as useful but I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't worry about the upvote, I'm just glad we worked through your problem and you can continue developing. It can be tricky working with new languages, and JS isn't exactly an easy one to dive into. :)

Comment: Latest version is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TVWYn/9/embedded/result/). It now responds to both x and y and it remembers the last mouse position before releasing the mouse button (so that the plane position doesn't reset each time you click again).